# PHP if statement doesn't work properly (paradoxical)

Tags: php, if-statement, image-upload

I've got a strange problem. I want to write a simple multiple image upload script in PHP. 
So there is an if statement I need for checking if the image has got the correct image type, which doesn't work as expected. The image I try to upload is a .jpg image. The "jpg" information is stored in the variable $mediaFileType, which is being checked by the if statement. Normally it should execute the script in the else statement now, but it always does the opposite and states that "jpg" != "jpg" = true. And it's obviously not. So what am I missing here?

```
if($mediaFileType != 'jpg' && $mediaFileType != 'png' && $mediaFileType != 'jpeg')
 {

    echo 'Wrong Media Type<br>';
    echo $mediaFileType;
    exit();

} else {
    ....
}
```

The website simply says:

```
Wrong Media Type
jpg
```

Comment: file extensions can't be the same for one file, you need to check using the "OR" operator. You might even want to post the html for this and the rest of the php

Comment: Try `!in_array()`, it can sometimes make things a little easier than multiple ifs. `!in_array($mediaFileType, ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'])`. If that doesn't work, try trimming `$mediaFileType`, or `var_dump($mediaFileType)` to make sure there aren't any extra characters.

Comment: You want to read about operator precedence... http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: Can you var_dump() mediaFileType instead of echoing it, please? The string is likely something with invisible white space characters.

Comment: try trimming $mediaFileType, `trim($mediaFileType)`

Comment: @Fred -ii- I guess its time for weekend! (With "OR" it would be the problem you describe)

Comment: @RolandStarke Partly. However, the OP failed to respond to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849421/php-if-statement-doesnt-work-properly-paradoxical#comment80646162_46849421) so he can take it up with answers given. I'll have to just see what the outcome is and make me a bowl of popcorn ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably a whitespace character

```
if (!in_array(trim($mediaFileType), ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']))
{
    echo 'Wrong Media Type<br/>';
    var_dump($mediaFileType);
    exit();
}
...
```

Comment: All of you were right by saying it was a whitespace character. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
if (!in_array(trim($mediaFileType), ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'])) {
    echo 'Wrong Media Type<br>';
    echo $mediaFileType;
    exit();
}
```